# Select2 Tagging in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, jquery-select2, ember-select

I'm developing an app that needs Tags, and i'm using select2. 
I've searched about this issue and found the following link:
https://github.com/iStefo/ember-select-2/pull/92

As far as I know there is a pull request that adds this functionality to the ember-select-2 add-on.

However I can't seem to get it to work with the following code:

```
{{select-2
  content=tag_list
  optionValuePath="name"
  optionLabelPath="name"
  optionIdPath="name"
  value=selectedTags
  multiple=true
  tags=true
  placeholder="Choose some Tags"
}}
```

The issue is that I can't add new tags that don't exist on the list being shown at the select2 dropdown.

If there is someone around that can help me i'll be very happy. :)

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't let me add new tags, only the ones that already exist.

Comment: Hmm can you find the function for "new tags" ? it should be handled by you somehwere... aka newTag="myNewTagFunction"

Comment: Well, i don't have one, i assumed that it wouldn't be needed since the Pull Request on the ember-select-2 addon doens't say anything about it.